Finding multiplicity of roots over finite fields
Let $f$ be a polynomial over a finite field $\mathbb F$ with $p^n$
elements. Given a root $a$ of $f$, is there a way to find its multiplicity using the derivatives, as done over $\mathbb R$?

Yes, there is: $a$ is root of multiplicity $\ge m$ of $f$ if $f^{(m-1)}(a)=0$.

@schiepy: the $p$-th derivative of $x^p(x-1)$ is zero, hence $1$ is a root of order $p+1$? Or $0$ is a root of $x^3+x$ with multiplicity $3$?

Ah, so you have to ensure that all the derivatives $f^{(i)}(a)=0$ for all $i\le m$. Kinda missed that.

A catch is that in characteristic $p$ the usual $p$th derivative is identically zero for all polynomials $f$. This is simply because differentiating $x^m$ $p$ times with the usual rule yields $m(m-1)\cdots(m-p+1)x^{m-p}$, and one of the integer factors is divisible by $p$ irrespective of choice of $m$.
This spells trouble for the usual way of calculating the order of a zero of a polynomial, when the order is $\ge p$.
The remedy is to modify the definition of higher order derivatives as follows. Let's restrict to the ring of univariate polynomials $K[x]$ where $K$ is a field (of characteristic $p$). For any natural number $k$ define the $k$th order differentiation $D^{[k]}:K[x]\to K[x]$ with the recipe that if
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^m a_i x^i,
$$
then
$$
D^{[k]}f(x)=\sum_{i=k}^m\binom i k a_i x^{i-k}.\tag{1}
$$
So in characteristic zero the connection to iterated usual derivatives $f^{(k)}$ reads
$$
D^{[k]}f(x)=\frac1{k!}f^{(k)}(x).
$$
The upshot is that in characteristic $p$ we cannot divide by the factorial when $k\ge p$. Yet the formula $(1)$ makes sense, because the binomial coefficients are integers, and integer multiples are unproblematic in any ring.
The price we need to pay is that the composition of higher order differentiation operators becomes a bit more complicated. A comparison with characteristic zero immediately gives us the formula, valid for all $k,\ell$:
$$
D^{[k]}\circ D^{[\ell]}=\binom {k+\ell} k D^{[k+\ell]}.\tag{2}
$$
Similarly, the usual general Leibniz rule for calculating higher order derivatives of products of two polynomials needs to be modified.
Anyway, for the purposes of this question the key is that we have the usual Taylor expansion. For any $\alpha \in K$ and any polynomial $f(x)\in K[x]$ we have
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty D^{[k]}f(\alpha)\,(x-\alpha)^k,
\tag{3}
$$
where the sum on the r.h.s. is obviously finite for every polynomial $f(x)$. The proof of $(3)$ is straight forward. It is easy to verify it in the case of a monomial $f(x)=x^m$, and the general case follows by linearity.
An answer can then be given in a language that doesn't markedly differ from the calculus answer. An element $\alpha\in K$ is a zero of order $m$ of a polynomial $f(x)$ if and only if $D^{[k]}f(\alpha)=0$ for all $k=0,1,\ldots, m-1$ and
$D^{[m]}f(\alpha)\neq0$.
Observe that only the characteristic of $K$ played a role — no need to restrict ourselves to finite fields.

I learned about these from Jens C. Jantzen's book (from 1980s) on Representation theory of algebraic groups, where he needed them to describe some properties of affine group schemes. He calls them (in multivariable case) distributions (on the group scheme under discussion). So the ideas were certainly used by scheme theorists earlier. I would be surprised if mathematicians like Carlitz and Dickson had not used them a century ago. Probably others earlier still.
I would welcome an answer by people familiar with scheme theory describing the current terminology as well as notation. I used notation like $D^{[k]}$ in my own dissertation because formula $(2)$ made many a necessary calculation possible. I don't remember where I found it, sorry.

Promoting stuff from an informative comment by user orangeskid. They found this Wikipedia article and the term Hasse derivative. Please check it out. You will see that the general Leibniz rule becomes very simple, indeed!

The idea is old. The last paragraph is more about my personal development as an algebraist rather than a scholarly historical account, which is exactly why I welcome other answers from learned users.

Neat answer, and found this: Hasse derivative
